# How to get a random value of a dictionary in swiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: swift, dictionary, alamofire, shuffle, swifty-json

I want to get **1 (one)** "value" in a **random** order with "localization" "NL" instead of the **whole** JSON response.result value.
How can I accomplish that?

Example:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "NL"
}
```

I have a JSON file with the following :

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "NL"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "NL"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "NL"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "EN"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "EN"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "value": "..",
    "localization": "EN"
}]
```

And with Alamofire I made a GET request:

```
func getRequestWithAlamofire(){
    Alamofire.request("linkwhereIhosttheJSONFile").responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model object for your JSON

```
struct Entry: Codable {
  let id, value, localization: String
}
```

and decode it using `JSONDecoder`:

```
do {
  let entries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Entry].self, from: data)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

once you have that you can easily pick a random element that has `localization == "NL"`:

```
let randomElement = entries.filter { $0.localization == "NL" }.randomElement()
```

(SwiftyJSON is not needed for any of this)